# Why doesn't the thread execute, or does it execute?

Tags: pascal, freepascal

I am trying to make a multithreaded random number generator for the command line interface, and for that I use TThreads to use multiple cpu cores to make random numbers. My program works till I try to start a thread, as it seemingly starts but, as far as I can tell, doesn't execute its code, because then my loop in line 196 should end, but it doesn't.

```
{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

uses
  {$IFDEF UNIX}
  cthreads,
  {$ENDIF}
  Classes,
  sysutils,
  math;

type

  TMyThread = class(TThread)
  private
    procedure ShowStatus;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create(CreateSuspended: boolean);
  end;

var
  nums, temp1: int64;
  f: tfilestream;
  split_char: char;
  commands: array[0..2] of int64;
  writing: boolean = false;
  done: array of boolean;

constructor TMyThread.Create(CreateSuspended: boolean);
begin
  FreeOnTerminate := True;
  inherited Create(CreateSuspended);
end;

procedure TMyThread.ShowStatus;
begin
  done[temp1]:= false;
end;

procedure TMyThread.Execute;
var
  s, temp: string;
  i: uint64;
begin
  Synchronize(@Showstatus);
  i:= temp1;
  s:= '';
  while not nums < 0 do
  begin
    writeln('test.................................');
    dec(nums);
    temp:= inttostr(randomrange(commands[1], commands[2])) +  split_char;
    if high(s) + high(temp) > 4096 then
    begin
      if not writing then
      begin
        writing:= true;
        f.Write(s[1], high(s));
        s:= temp;
        writing:= false;
      end;
    end
    else
     s:= s + temp;
  end;
  done[i]:= true;
end;

var
  i, timestamp, timestamp2: uint64;
  temp, cores: int64;
  f_temp, temp_s: string;
  close, time, written, writeable, file_specified, numbers_specified, range_specified, split_char_specified: boolean;
  is_finished: boolean = false;
  threads: array of TMyThread;

label
  jump;

begin
  timestamp:= gettickcount64;
  time:= false;
  writeable:= false;
  written:= false;
  file_specified:= false;
  numbers_specified:= false;
  range_specified:= false;
  split_char_specified:= false;
  cores:= 0;
  for i:= 1 to paramcount() do
  try
      case paramstr(i) of
      '/f', '/file': begin
                       file_specified:= true;
                       f_temp:= paramstr(i + 1).split('"')[0];
                      if fileexists(f_temp) then
                        deletefile(f_temp);
                      f:= tfilestream.create(f_temp, fmcreate);
                      writeable:= true;
                    end;
      '/n', '/numbers': begin
                         numbers_specified:= true;
                         commands[0]:= strtoint(paramstr(i + 1)) - 1;
                       end;
      '/r', '/range': begin
                        range_specified:= true;
                        commands[1]:= strtoint((paramstr(i + 1).split(';'))[0]);
                        commands[2]:= strtoint((paramstr(i + 1).split(';'))[1]) + 1;
                      end;
      '/s', '/split', 'splitchar': begin
                                     split_char_specified:= true;
                                     split_char:=paramstr(i + 1)[1];
                                   end;
      '/t', '/time': time:= true;
      '/tr', '/truerand': randomize;
      '/c', '/cores': cores:= strtoint(paramstr(i + 1));
      end;
    except
      if not writeable then
      begin
        write('cannot write to file');
        written:= true;
      end;
      close:= true;
    end;
  if not file_specified then
      begin
        write('file not specified');
        written:= true;
        close:= true;
      end;
  if numbers_specified then
      begin
        if commands[0] < 1 then
        begin
          if written then
            write(#13);
          write('cannot generate <1 numbers');
          written:= true;
          close:= true;
        end;
      end
      else
      begin
        if written then
          write(#13);
        write('amount of numbers not specified');
        written:= true;
        close:= true;
      end;
      if not range_specified then
      begin
        if written then
          write(#13);
        write('range not specified');
        written:= true;
        close:= true;
      end
      else
        if commands[1] = commands[2] then
        begin
          temp:= commands[1];
          commands[2]:= commands[1];
          commands[2]:= temp;
        end;
      if not split_char_specified then
      begin
        if written then
          write(#13);
        write('split-char not specified');
        close:= true;
      end;
  if close then
    halt;
  try
    if (cores = 0) or (cores > getcpucount) then
      cores:= getcpucount;
    setlength(threads, cores);
    setlength(done, cores);
    for i:= low(threads) to high(threads) do
      threads[i]:= default(Tmythread);
    nums:= commands[0];
    writeln(inttostr(length(threads)));
    writeln('test0');
    writeln('threadcount: ' + inttostr(length(threads)));
    for i:= low(threads) to high(threads) do
    begin
      writeln('test?');
      threads[i].create(true);
      writeln('thread ' + inttostr(i) + ' initialized');
      temp1:= i;
      done[temp1]:= true;
      while done[temp1] = true do
      begin
        writeln('waiting for thread to start');
      end;
    end;
    writeln('test1');
    while not is_finished do
    begin
      i:= 0;
      jump:
      if not done[i] then
      goto jump;
      inc(i);
      if i = high(done) then
      is_finished:= true;
    end;
    temp_s:= inttostr(randomrange(commands[1], commands[2])) +  split_char;
    f.Write(temp_s[1], high(temp_s));
  except
    on e: exception do
    begin
      write(#13 + e.message);
      deletefile(paramstr(i));
      write('ERROR! Program will exit');
      exit;
    end;
  end;
  f.free;
  if time then
  begin
    if written then
      write(#13);
    write(floattostr((gettickcount64 - timestamp) / 1000) + ' seconds to execute');
  end;
end.
```

Comment: `CreateSuspended` literally means just that - didn't you ever wonder about that?

Comment: And by the way, that's code written in FPC or Lazarus, but normally not Delphi (although it can be compatible, of course)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of problems with your threads:

- `threads[i].create(true);` is the wrong way to create the thread objects. You need to use `threads[i] := TMyThread.Create(true);` instead.
- you are creating each thread with `CreateSuspended=True`, but you don't call `Start()` on any of the threads to resume them so they actually run.
- your `Execute()` method is calling `Synchronize()` as its very 1st statement.  But your project is a console app without a message loop that processes `Synchronize()` requests, so all of your threads will deadlock immediately.  At the very least, your main thread needs to call `Classes.CheckSynchronize()` periodically while the worker threads are running.
- your threads are sharing and modifying global variables without any synchronization between them. Any variables that don't need to be shared globally (like each thread's array index) should be passed to the thread's constructor and stored in class members instead.
- the way you are waiting for the threads to finish running is both incorrect and inefficient.